# No disk space left on root

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount, raid

When I restarted my computer, which is running Ubuntu 12.04, I got a message that there was 0 disk space left on `/`.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        19G   18G     0 100% /
udev            7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  944K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G  512K  7.9G   1% /run/shm
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sda1        89M   33M   51M  40% /boot
/dev/md127p1    917G  179G  692G  21% /mnt/data0
/dev/sda5       892G  137G  710G  17% /home
```

Using the Disk Usage Analyzer, I again see that `/` is 100% full, with 54% in `/mnt` and 43% in `/home`. I have a few questions:

1. I have a RAID 1 array mounted at `/mnt/data0`. Why does this disk usage show up within `/`?
2. I have deleted 10s of GB of unnecessary files from `/home` with seemingly no affect on the disk usage percent in `/` (it still says 100% usage). Is there somewhere else I should be looking to delete files?

Comment: `df` reports the usage of all filesystems, run `df /mount/point` to get the space of a filesystem, i.e. in your case `df /` and please edit your question, because you mean the "root" filesystem `/` and not `/root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home` is on a different filesystem (last line of your `df` command output) and `/mnt/data0` doesn't show up within `/` but as 21% full.

In order to get your system back to work, you need to free space on the `/` filesystem only, where also your `/root` directory is located.

Best thing is to check, where all the space has gone with the `du -s` command:

I.e.:

```
cd /
du -s *
```

Then cd to the directory with the largest number in front and type:

```
du -s *
```

And so on. At some point you will find some large files and may choose to remove them to free up space.

Comment: You want to add -x to `du` to make it ignore files on other partitions.  If that still shows a bunch of used space in /mnt, then you have junk in there that shouldn't be ( and isn't in /mnt/data0 ).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Alex. I'm hesitant to delete files in / without knowing what they are... Are there any specific places you would look?

Comment: Is it okay to remove old linux-header-* and linux-header-*-generic files from /usr/src? I have seen various posts on this, but what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I'd first look in /var, expecially in /var/log and /var/tmp. Also in /root, the home directory of the root user. Also follow the suggestion of psusi above - it seems indeed that you have things other than the mountpoint /mnt/data0 (usually an empty directory) and in your /mnt directory (usually empty as well).

Comment: Thanks. My /var directory is not contributing much to the problem. However, I realized that I have the Intel Composer taking up ~5G in /opt. Is it possible to move this somewhere else, but put a symbolic link in its place in order to not break any existing dependencies or paths to that directory?

Comment: Yes, normally this should work. You can move the directory to another filesystem and then create a symbolic link to the new location under /opt.